# Send method to each object in Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I want to send an method to each object in an Array. I know I can do something like this

```
array = ...
array.each { |obj| obj.some_method }
```

But is there a method where I can do something like the following?

```
array = ...
array.send_each :some_method
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

```
array.each(&:some_method)
```

Comment: Which is shorthand for `array.each{ |object| object.some_method }`. Use that version if you need to pass parameters to the method.

Comment: @Thilo That's pretty redundant, given that's the exact code posted in the question... Also not correct. It's short-hand for `array.each(&Proc.new { |x| x.some_method })`.